# Use OpenIDM as data user source for OpenAM

Tags: single-sign-on, openam, openidm

Can you tell me if we can use OpenIDM as data store for OpenAM instead of OpenDJ ?

I search on internet and i found nothing.

If is it possible do you have a documentation page that can help me ? 
If not what is the best practice to manage user identity and authentication with OpenIDM and OpenAM ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using OpenDJ as a backend for both OpenAM and OpenIDM. I do not think there is any easy or good way to use OpenIDM directly with OpenAM (but if anyone finds out, please let me know). Also, by using OpenDJ as a backend, there is no dependencies between OpenIDM and OpenAM.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer : No.

Long Answer : 
It would be beneficial to clear some things out.

**OpenDJ** is an implementation of an ldap server written in Java.

**OpenIDM** is a provisioning engine implementation written in Java. It uses a user and data repository, that can be a MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle DB, etc.

Reading your question, I get the idea that you are wondering if you can use OpenIDM's user repository as, your OpenAM user repository , and hence the answer is no.

What you would have to do is to set up synchronization between the OpenIDM data store and an Ldap server ( could be OpenDJ ), so that you can provision users and entitlements to the ldap server and use that as OpenAM's user base repository.

Answer (score 1):

Use the openidm samples/sample2c. This example provides a way for opendj to be synched with openidm. The opendj can be a store for openAM.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenIDM repository cannot be utilized as the user store for OpenAM.